# If/else condition in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

I recently started to "coding" and I'm really really into the beginning and this is one of my first "projects". It is supposed to be SI converter where you can type value, its unit and the unit you want it to be converted.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            decimal one = 1;
            decimal two = 0.001m;
            decimal three = 0.000001m;
            decimal four = 0.000000001m;
            decimal five = 0.000000000001m;
            decimal answer;


       begn: Console.WriteLine("SI converter!\nPlease, enter value: ");             
            decimal value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("\nFactors: \n1.One \n2.Milli(m)\n3.Micro(µ)\n4.Nano(n)\n5.Pico(p)\nEnter factor: "); 
            decimal factor = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (factor == 1)
            {
                factor = one;
            }else if (factor == 2)
            {
                factor = two;
            }else if (factor == 3)
            {
                factor = three;
            }else if (factor == 4)
            {
                factor = four;
            }else if (factor == 5)
            {
                factor = five;
            }


            Console.WriteLine("\nFactors: \n1.One \n2.Milli(m)\n3.Micro(µ)\n4.Nano(n)\n5.Pico(p)\nEnter the second factor: ");
            decimal factor2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (factor2 == 1)
            {
                factor2 = one;
                answer = value * factor;
                Console.WriteLine("The answer is : " + answer);
            }
            else if (factor2 == 2)
            {
                factor2 = two;
            }
            else if (factor2 == 3)
            {
                factor2 = three;
            }
            else if (factor2 == 4)
            {
                factor2 = four;
            }
            else if (factor2 == 5)
            {
                factor2 = five;
            }



                answer = value * factor / factor2;                      
                Console.WriteLine("The answer is : " + answer);


            Console.WriteLine("Go again?\nY / N");          
            char ans =char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (ans == 'y')
            {
                Console.Clear();
                goto begn;

            }
            if(ans=='n')
            {

                Console.ReadKey();
            }


        }


        }
    }
```

So the problem is that I don't really like this part and I don't have any idea how to do it :

```
 if (factor == 1)
            {
                factor = one;
            }else if (factor == 2)
            {
                factor = two;
            }else if (factor == 3)
            {
                factor = three;
            }else if (factor == 4)
            {
                factor = four;
            }else if (factor == 5)
            {
                factor = five;
            }
```

P.S Yes I know its probably really really bad, but its my first try.And if you can give me any tips I'll be really happy :)

Comment: I don't get it...what's wrong with the code?

Comment: First advice to a beginner programmer: do yourself a favor and forget about the `goto` keyword ;). Use a loop instead.

Comment: Better advice, ignore the above comment and do what you need to do. Style and finesse comes later

Comment: When condition is an integral value (as in your case), you can replace a bunch of sequential IF's with `switch` statement: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx and remove `goto` from your code. Replace is with a loop or external method.

Comment: @bitwise wow I wouldn't want you coding on my team if you were using `goto`

Comment: @bitwise, codestyling -- maybe, but when you use `goto` in C#, you are creating a very BAD code. Someone else (maybe you?) will support in in production.

Comment: @CryptoGuy because this guy's code is going into production tomorrow....right? =/

Comment: Okay I'll keep in mind to never use goto anymore :)

Comment: Are you sure if this code isn't going to production? Please, stop debating, this thread goes to nowhere. Say NO to `goto`. Period.

Comment: What OP needs is a lookup table anyways, not one condition per case.

Comment: I think *code review exchange* is better place to ask:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you have working code and only want to improve it, you can head to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). SO is for programming problems, not general advice on code quality.

Comment: Oh ok I' ll move my question there immediately. Thanks for the help everyone :)

Comment: for someone wants to follow the question:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112636/si-unit-converter

Answer (score 1):

Use Switch condition

```
switch (factor)
         {
            case 1:
               factor = one;
               break;
            case 2:
               factor = two;
               break;
            case 3:
               factor = three;
               break;
            case 4:
                factor = four;
               break;
               default:
                //default when nothing happens in switch
                factor = one;
               break;
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static decimal[,] factors = new decimal[4, 4] {
            /*               To Milli        To Micro    To Nano,  To Pico    */
            /* From Milli */ { 1m,           1000m,      1000000m, 1000000000m },
            /* From Micro */ { 0.001m,       1m,         1000m,    1000000m    },
            /* From Nano  */ { 0.000001m,    0.001m,     1m,       1000m       },
            /* From Pico  */ { 0.000000001m, 0.000001m,  0.001m,   1m          }
        };

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SI converter!");

            while(true)
            {
                Console.Write("Please, enter value: ");
                decimal value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("\n1) Milli(m)\n2) Micro(µ)\n3) Nano(n)\n4) Pico(p)\nFrom Units: ");
                int fromUnits = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 1;

                Console.Write("To Units: ");
                int toUnits = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 1;

                decimal factor = factors[fromUnits, toUnits];
                decimal answer = factor * value;
                Console.WriteLine("The answer is : " + answer);

                Console.Write("Go again? (Y/N): ");    
                string ans = Console.ReadLine();

                if(ans.ToUpper() == "N")
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: desperately resisting the urge to rewrite my example using goto... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more dynamically by creating a array with the different values and their appropriate text. Then just print the related text with the value of the array column.

```
string[] arrayText = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
//Remember than your array start at 0
factor= factor - 1;
System.console.WriteLine(arrayText[factor]);
```

I think that this is what you want!

Answer (score 0):

In place of the `if/else` block, you can use a `Dictionary<string, decimal>` where the `key` (a string) is your expected inputs and the `value` (a decimal) is the variable the input corresponds to.

You can build this dictionary in a separate method when the app starts up, as these values won't change. Make the dictionary available to the rest of your program (using `public`, for example), and you can re-use this information anywhere you need to with the same simple check.

Once the dictionary is built, all you have to do is check if the dictionary contains the input value and set `factor1` (or `factor2`) accordingly:

```
 string input;
 decimal factor1;

 Dictionary<string, decimal> factors = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

 factors.Add("1", one);
 factors.Add("2", two);
 factors.Add("3", three);
 factors.Add("4", four);
 factors.Add("5", five);

 input = Console.ReadLine();

 if (factors.ContainsKey(input))
 {
    factor1 = factors["input"];
 }
```

You should also consider adding an `else` condition somewhere along the lines of `you screwed up, try again` to prompt the user to re-enter a value.

Also, in your current code, don't re-use the `factor` variable for both input and calculations. Just take the input as a string and check against specific values.

For additional help, I'd suggest CodeReview as has been recommended in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code similar to this:

```
decimal answer;
decimal[] factorArray = new decimal[] { 1, 0.001m, 0.000001m, 0.000000001m, 0.000000000001m };

Console.WriteLine("SI converter!\nPlease, enter value: ");
decimal value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("\nFactors: \n1.One \n2.Milli(m)\n3.Micro(µ)\n4.Nano(n)\n5.Pico(p)\nEnter factor: ");
decimal factor = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if (factor >= 1 && factor <= factorArray.Length)
{
    factor = factorArray[(int)factor - 1];
}

Console.WriteLine("\nFactors: \n1.One \n2.Milli(m)\n3.Micro(µ)\n4.Nano(n)\n5.Pico(p)\nEnter the second factor: ");
decimal factor2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if (factor2 >= 1 && factor2 <= factorArray.Length)
{
    factor2 = factorArray[(int)factor2 - 1];
}
```